# ncurses program won't run on debian armv7

Tags: linux, arm, debian, ncurses

Can somebody here help me with ncurses for armv7 (x86)? I just want to run on Debian my C++ program uses ncurses It has error "Error opening terminal: xterm."

I used this installation guide: http://soft-dev-pro.blogspot.ru/2014/07/cross-compile-ncurses-for-arm.html

If i type which in console, it shows this: which $TERM /usr/bin/xterm

It seems initscr() function won't start curses mode

Comment: " find /usr/share/terminfo/ -type f " shows this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HR5iOuRGEqt1R3Gf9A3vhO56BX7elxET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ncurses program is looking for

```
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/share/terminfo
```

and not finding that.  If you do

```
export TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
```

then the program can use that setting to find the system's terminal database.